# How to Handle Angular2 http request with Query Parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I Have Tried

```
http.get('http://192.168.0.26:9000/api/task/counttask?projectid=-1&Teamid=-1&RoleId=-1&status=1&PID=-1&mytasks=0&alltasks=0&page=1&row=15&priorityid=-1&typeid=-1&taskname=&JSON&_=1471520478215')

    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => this.result = res); 
     alert(this.result);
```

**I am Getting Error But if You run this below Url in Browser it will give you the output**

> 192.168.0.26:9000/api/task/counttask?projectid=-1&Teamid=-1&RoleId=-1&status=1&PID=-1&mytasks=0&alltasks=0&page=1&row=15&priorityid=-1&typeid=-1&taskname=&JSON&_=1471520478215

How to Handle this Request ??

Comment: In your `map` function, it shouldn't be `.map((res) => res.json())`?

Comment: What i have to give on that place ?

Comment: `(res: Response) => res.json()` is not correct in syntax. I think that it should be `res => res.json()`

Comment: `(res: Response) => res.json()` is totally fine and won't make any difference in the produced JavaScript

Comment: @j2L4e  Give me some i idea ... post the answer with the below url ...  i will upvote ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: It'd be nice to know the actual error.

Your `alert()` is executed right away. So the request hasn't finished yet.
 Try this:

```
.subscribe(res => {
  this.result = res;
  console.log(this.result);
});
```

edit: you should use console.log (or an actual debugger), because alert() does not resolve objects. It might just say "[object Object]".

Comment: Thanks a lot Its Working ... I cannot upvote because it needs atleast 15 reputation ....